# jstl invalid prefix error

Tags: jsp, websphere, jsp-tags

I am using similar piece of code in a jspx file

```
<html
xmlns:jsp="http://java.sun.com/JSP/Page"
xmlns:uikit="http://www.abc.net/ld/uikit"           >

<head>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="${uikit:cpp('abc')}"/>
```

but its throws the error

jsp.error.attribute.invalidPrefix uikit

The cpp function is defined in the uikit.tld file.
The above code works perfectly fine on tomcat, but gives error on Websphere 7.0.0.19.

Any idea what might be going wrong ?

Comment: Still occurs in WebSphere 8. Is there a setting that can be changed somewhere?